# Python join two pandas dataframes on multiple columns with waterfall logic

Tags: python, pandas, join, waterfall

I have two dataframes with multiple columns in common. I want to do a join between the two dataframes but with waterfall logic based on column order. For example, in the example below, I want key1 column to take priority. If key1 is null or if key1 cannot be found in df_map, then use the key2 column, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
df_map = pd.DataFrame([["a","b", 1],["x","y", 2]], columns=["key1", "key2", "val"])
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,"b"],["x", np.nan]], columns=["key1", "key2"])
res = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,"b", 1],["x", np.nan, 2]], columns=["key1", "key2", "val"])
```

Inputs:

```
df
Out[120]: 
  key1 key2
0  NaN    b
1    x  NaN

df_map
Out[121]: 
  key1 key2  val
0    a    b    1
1    x    y    2
```

Desired output:

```
res
Out[126]: 
  key1 key2  val
0  NaN    b    1
1    x  NaN    2
```

Comment: why val is 2???

Comment: thanks for catching that bug, i have fixed it

Comment: I'd solve this by adding a temporary column "usable_key"  into your first df. You can use your waterfall logic to determine this key and then perform a normal mapping using the newly created column.